# How to load required dependencies instead of a bunch of them

Tags: angular

I'm newbie in Angular development, and I'm developing a asp.net core app with an angular8 front-end, however I noticed that a bunch of files were downloaded into node_modules folder, maybe some of them will be used into the app but many of the rest, maybe won't.

Is there any way to configure the angular project to load libraries by demand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular only loads the depencencies as you import them, like the example below:

```
import { RecaptchaModule, RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';
```

As you build your Angular for production, only the dependencies listed in json property "dependencies" in your `package.json` file in the root of your project will be used.